# pi-robot pkg for kinect - process has died error

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, openni-camera, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After installing openni_camera and pi-robot package (skeleton_markers and pi_tracker), I've been trying to run the skeleton tracking launch files, but always fails with the message like this:

[tracker_joint_controller-3] process has died [pid 23481, exit code 1, cmd /home/daikii/fuerte_workspace/pi-robot/pi_tracker/bin/tracker_joint_controller.py __name:=tracker_joint_controller __log:=/home/daikii/.ros/log/0bc93050-1ad4-11e2-80a6-001b63050e97/tracker_joint_controller-3.log].
log file: /home/daikii/.ros/log/0bc93050-1ad4-11e2-80a6-001b63050e97/tracker_joint_controller-3*.log

Can anyone specify what this message is trying to tell me? I tried modifying the launch files, checking directories, and etc, but I can't pinpoint the problem.

I am running ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you so much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46368/pi-robot-pkg-for-kinect---process-has-died-error/) by [daikii](https://answers.ros.org/users/3405/daikii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I maintain the pi_tracker and skeleton_markers packages but they were written for ROS Electric.  However, I just now added some Fuerte-specific launch and RViz files.  To try it out, first do the following:

```
$ roscd skeleton_markers
$ svn update
$ rosmake --pre-clean skeleton_markers

$ roscd pi_tracker
$ svn update
$ rosmake --pre-clean pi_tracker
```

Then you should be able to launch the openni tracker and pi_tracker using the following:

```
$ roslaunch pi_tracker skeleton_fuerte.launch
$ roslaunch pi_tracker tracker.launch
$ rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find pi_tracker`/tracker_rviz_fuerte.vcg
```

--patrick

http://www.pirobot.org

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1